# Почему не импортируется класс IdentityDbContext<T> из EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Users.Models
{
    public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0), надо написать:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

На крайняк неймспейс можно и [на гитхабе](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityDbContext.cs) найти.